# Why am I getting an error while trying to run this on dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

the operator '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be null.

```
var numbers = <int>[1,3,2,5,4];

var initialValue = 10;

void main() {
  var foldNum = numbers.fold(initialValue, (curr, next) => (curr + next));
  print(foldNum);
}
```

Comment: Try it this way `var foldNum = numbers.fold(initialValue, (curr, next) => ((curr as int) + next));` OR
`var foldNum = numbers.fold(initialValue, (int curr,int next) => (curr + next));`

Answer (score 2):

Specify the type of `fold` as `fold<int>`...

```
var numbers = <int>[1,3,2,5,4];

var initialValue = 10;

void main() {
  var foldNum = numbers.fold<int>(initialValue, (curr, next) => (curr + next));
  print(foldNum);
}
```

Comment: Thanks..it worked